# SQL to group the records added over a period of time

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table like this.These are the orders made by a particular customer over a period of time.

I want to get the data in such a way that when a customer makes a transaction, I have to check for 7 days to see what other transactions are performed by the customer.

In this case on 18th July 2022, the customer made the first transaction and within 7 days there is no other transaction so in the output there will be only 1 row with total orders=1. Going forward the customer made another transaction on 30th July 2022(ERT) and within 7 days of that transaction there are 4 other transactions(DFT,HGF,BGT,RET).

So this has to give another row in the output for the same customer id but with the new order date as 30th Jul 2022 and with a total of 5 orders within 7 days after this transaction.

Is there a way to achieve this in BigQuery?

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we don't know when a new transaction begins, we need an UDF which returns zero if a cumulative sum of elapsed days between transactions passes over a given threshold (7 days in this case).

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION cumulative_sum_binning(a ARRAY<INT64>) RETURNS INT64
LANGUAGE js AS """
  bin = 1;
  a.reduce((c, v) => {
    if (c + Number(v) > 6) { bin += 1; return 0; }
    else return c += Number(v); 
  }, 0);

  return bin;
""";

SELECT * EXCEPT(diff), 'tx_' || cumulative_sum_binning(ARRAY_AGG(diff) OVER w1) transaction FROM (
  SELECT *,
         DATE_DIFF(order_date, LAG(order_date) OVER w0, DAY) AS diff 
    FROM (
      SELECT * REPLACE(PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', order_date) AS order_date)
        FROM orders
    )
  WINDOW w0 AS (PARTITION BY custId ORDER BY order_date)
) WINDOW w1 AS (PARTITION BY custId ORDER BY order_date);
```

Above query shows below result.

**Query results**

[image]

For your expected output,

```
SELECT custId, MIN(order_date) order_date, COUNT(tx) total_orders FROM (
 -- put above *select* query here
) GROUP BY custId, tx
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. It is working fine with smaller set of data. when it comes to millions of records, it is taking more than 30 mins to execute. Is it because the UDF is in js instead of SQL? Is there a way to optimize this solution?

Comment: @ANANTH, How many days in your dataset for each user ? Basically this is a cumulative approach which doesn't show a goog performance.

Comment: it will have around 100 million+ records. (over 2 years) Is there any way to optimize this?

Comment: Is it working for a small number of users (i.e 100,000 or so ?)

Comment: It fails with the following error: UDF worker timed out during execution.

Comment: and `order_date` is a type of `DATE`, NOT `DATE_TIME` or `TIMESTAMP`  right ?
and it seems a user can have multiple transactions in a day, correct ?
(my apology for too many questions)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252574/discussion-between-jaytiger-and-ananth).